# Parsing arguments with defaults and flags

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

I've got a ruby bin with some arguments, namely `-s`, `-c` and `-r` (short for scrape, create and run). Now I'd like to set some defaults to scrape and create (`'.'` in both cases), but if I use `:default` in trollop, I can't check wherever that argument is set or not.

```
project --scrape
```

should be equivalent to

```
project --scrape .
```

how to achieve that?

And while at it, how do I make

```
project target
```

to be equivalent with

```
project --run target
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `ARGV` before Trollop processes it.  Your best bet would probably be to scan the input arguments, apply some basic transformations, and then run Trollop.

For example:

```
args = ARGV.split
idx = args.index '--scrape'
if idx != nil
    if idx < args.length
        if args[idx + 1][0..1] == '--'
            args=args[0..idx] + ['.'] + args[idx+1..-1]
        end
    else
        if args[idx + 1][0..1] == '--'
            args << '.'
        end
    end
end
```

This snippet should check for `--scrape` with no parameter following it and add in a `'.'` in that case.  You can do something similar to check for the omitted `--run` parameter.  When you are done making your modifications, use `args.join(' ')` to put the arguments back together into a string.  Assign this new string to `ARGV`, and then set Trollop loose.